# Art of War: Do not criticize your enemies?

Tags: eastern-philosophy, philosophy-of-war

I read [The Art of War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_War) by [Sun Tzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Tzu) but don't recall the author mentioning anything directly regarding criticizing one's enemies.  It seems that when you get into an argument with your enemy and start criticizing him/her, then it's a no-win situation because:

1. winning the argument is usually returns no reward (a hollow victory at best), and
2. he/she could privately evaluate your criticisms and end-up changing for the better, which is not what you want. In other words, the worst thing you could do is tell your enemy where there weaknesses are.

Has anything like this been discussed before?  Sports philosophy, perhaps?

Edit 2:  Some may be getting confused between the choice of words: criticize and argument.  I'm not talking about an intellectual argument and I should perhaps strike it from this question but I'll leave it for now.  The key word is in the title, "criticize".

Edit:  Some are mistakenly re-framing this question from a 'war' context to something more civil, and from an 'enemy' context to something more like a casual argument.  Please, this question is about war and mortal enemies.  Do not be tempted to reduce the gravity of the situation because I mentioned sports.  In sports they use the term opponent instead of enemy, so for the purposes of this question, assume that a sports competition is played with the same fervor as a wartime battle (which they most certainly are most of the time).  Again, this question pertains to war strategy in the literal sense and only secondarily can be extended to pertain to a sports competition.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to clarify your concern here, but is there any chance I could persuade you to consider cleaning this up a little bit more? One way to reframe this might be: "Which philosophers have discussed [or advocated] avoiding polemics?" -- if that does really capture the problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the connection with the Art of War is. Is there any relevance at all? That it mentions enemies and you have a question about enemies?

Answer (score 3):

Well, one could argue that your proposed statement follows from Nietzsche's "That which does not kill me makes me stronger", but there are several problems with your formulation.

First, there is no particular reason to think that *"winning the argument usually returns no reward (a hollow victory at best)".*  In many situations, winning an argument has actual (non-hollow) consequences, not the least of which is a closer approximation of the truth (if both sides are arguing in good faith).

Second, there is no particular reason to think that I would be disappointed if my "enemy" changed for the better. If my opponent comes to follow my point of view, I imagine I would have reason to be pleased, not disappointed.

Which leads us to the most serious objection, the framing in terms of an "enemy" in the first place.  Philosophical opponents are rarely viewed as "enemies", even in polemical debates.

So: no, to the best of my knowledge, this notion has not be seriously entertained by any philosophers of renown, but I stand prepared to be corrected on this (and would not take such correction to be a "defeat" by an "enemy").

*An aside regarding the Nietzsche quote: like most of Nietzsche's aphorisms, we shouldn't be too hasty in interpreting those words without a closer examination of the context in which they appear...*

Comment: re: your aside about the Nietzsche quote - I've heard that it was possibly meant tongue in cheek, making fun of the Prussian military culture.

Comment: @Michael, the question makes it clear that I am not talking about a civil discourse with "philosophical opponents".  I see no reason to second guess what I mean by enemy.  I'm talking about war with real enemies.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but a critique of the question and a comment would be more appropriate.  If the answerer would justify why he/she thinks my statement "follows" from Nietzshe's statement, that would be more of an answer.  But, I don't see how the two statements have any relation at all.

Comment: @Tom: if you are asking about a war with real enemies, then the notion of "criticize" is not relevant.  Was there a point during WWII where the Allies, for example, considered sending a memo to the Axis offering a constructive critique of their performance thus far and suggesting proposed improvements?  The notion is nonsensical, and if that is what you were getting at, irrelevant to the *philosophy* stackexchange.

Comment: @Tom: as for the Nietzsche, I didn't think I was being too oblique, but just to spell it out completely: if one believes that "that which does not kill me makes me stronger", and also believes that this notion is not unique to the speaker but applies to all people, then it would follow that "that which does not kill one's enemy makes him stronger"; thus, any attack which is not sufficient to destroy the enemy completely would leave him stronger than before.  I leave the criticism of this argument as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Dorfman, again, war does not suggest any kind of "constructive critique".  Face it, you misinterpreted the question.  "Criticize" is not relevant???  Please, read the Art of War before commenting further.  Finally, you leave the readers an exercise?  WTF?  Just who do you think you are?  lol

Comment: @Tom: I was attempting (according to Gadamer's "Principle of Charity") to construe the question in a manner that best fit the context of this site; I apologize if I misinterpreted your intentions.  I have, indeed, read the Art of War, and offered the Nietzsche quote as the only relevant passage I know of in the philosophical literature (since that is, after all, what this site is about.)  I left the (obvious) criticism of Nietzsche's idea as an exercise for the reader as we are given a very small quantity of characters to work with in the comment field here, and I have once again exhausted it.

Answer (score 2):

Propaganda is a useful form of warfare.  Critizing you enemy to your people can either make them fear the less ([As the US did with the Japanese during WWII](http://media.brainz.org/uploads/2010/03/propaganda/Anti-Jap1.jpg)) or make them fear them more to get behind the fight against them([As with the "War on Terror"](http://www.globalissues.org/article/352/mainstream-media-and-propaganda)).  It can make your enemies people less willing to back the fight.  And it can break the will of the soldier on the front line.

While in an arguement [Ad Hominim](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/ad-hominem.html) attacks are generally a sign of a weak position, in warfare they can be effective.  In war, as in politics, it is often more important to appear to be correct than to actually be correct.

Comment: yes, it occurred to me about propaganda, which could mostly consist of lies in the first place.  This may not unintentionally help your enemy so much as long as you can assure that you don't enlighten him/her about any real weaknesses that they are not aware of.

Comment: What would be a weak argument to the educated is often a very compelling argument to the uneducated. Ad hominim, strawman, anecdotal, correlation/causation misrepresentations, flat out lies and even self-contradiction, all these form the basis of arguments that anyone with a logical mind sees right through but the masses do not. Of course, ethics plays a large part here - is it ethical to lie to someone if it leads them to a better position than if you'd've told the truth?

Comment: @glowcoder - War and ethics really do not belong together.  Is it ethical to blow someone up because you do not agree with thier policies, or want something they have?  The art of war is about accomplishing a military objective not about doing so ethically.

Comment: @Tom - Propaganda is argueably more effective when it is true just skewed.  Most conspiracy theories are boosted by some truth that can be used to point to a nefarious plot.  And the truth is what the people believe it is.

Comment: @Chad but there are ethics in war. For example, most civilizations have agreed to leave civilians unharmed if possible. Most civilizations have agreed to the protections of the Geneva convention (even if they are broken from time to time, which is constantly decried as unethical.) But regardless, my previous comment has nothing to do with war. Sure it could be used to support (or not support) a war, but it could be used for many many other purposes.

Comment: @Glowcoder - The point of the art of war is about winning a war.  It is not about the ethics of war and when you should our should not start a war.  Many of the principles of war can be applied to business and politics but that is not what the book is about.  Was it unethical for the allies to go into the schools across europe and teach that pride in country is bad?  Thats what we did post wwii.

Comment: @Chad Again, you're using my statement out of context. I'm not referring to the book, merely responding to the notion of propaganda and the style of attacks it uses.

Comment: @Glowcoder but this question is(Was anyway) about the book not actual war.  However if i can win the war by lying or by killing more people I will choose the lie as while it may be less ethical on the honesty scale its more ethical on my humanity scale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a saying, Do not argue with a fool as others can not tell the difference! Also consider yourself and your enemy both as parts of something else. In essense step outside of your argument and your oponent ( emphesis on oponent not enemy ) and view it as if your are viewing two people argueing with each other. Do not take sides with people but with the reason of the arguments, and not the arguments itself.